# SQL selecting and joining two values from table into another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, "teams" and "matches". I want to select and replace two team ID's from matches table with actual team names. I am able to get only one team name and I am not sure how I could select two.

```
SELECT m.*, t.teamId, t.teamName FROM matches AS m
JOIN teams AS t ON m.homeTeam = t.teamId
```

Matches Table

```
ID*
Date
homeTeam (id)
awayTeam (id)
```

Teams Table

```
ID*
Name
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join your `teams` table twice. Once for each team entry in your `matches` table. It should look something like this

```sql
SELECT 
  m.id
  , m.date
  , h.teamId as homeTeamID
  , h.teamName as homeTeamName
  , a.teamId as awayTeamID
  , a.teamName as awayTeamName
FROM 
  matches AS m
  JOIN teams AS h -- home team 
    ON m.homeTeam = h.teamId
  JOIN teams AS a -- away team
    on m.awayTeam = a.teamId
```

I've had to guess what you named the fields, but this should be enough to get you started.